# What is the best way to store application data accessible from all user accounts?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, security, keychain

I need to store some data so it can be accessed by the application from any user account.

The amount of data is not big, just several strings.

The storage does not have to be secure, although it would be beneficial. A least the users without admin permission should not be able to spoil it.

I would not mind if the application would require to provide admin password to store the data or remove it. However, when application is launched from another user account without admin rights, it should be able to read this data not asking for any passwords.

Should I use keychain or /Library/Application Support/ folder or maybe something else?

Comment: Yeah, `/Library/Application Support` would be the place to store info that needs to be accessible to multiple users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share file between different users by using [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).
[Working with Access Control Lists](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/IdentityServices_ProgGuide/WorkingwithAccessControlLists/WorkingwithAccessControlLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004490-CH7-SW3)
[Share any files between users on the same Mac](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090219133314985) 
[Make a folder read-write for all users without using ACLs](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100202195536952) 
I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try it. The third link is broken. Could you fix it please?